# What kind of NW USA insect Is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

What kind of insect is this? I saw it outdoors.

Comment: Looks like a nymph of some sort, the wings aren't developed yet.

Comment: This is a leafhopper nymph (order Hemiptera, family Cicadellidae); going deeper than that will depend on whether or not the species seen here has been reared.